# Setting multiple timers in a C socket communication

Tags: c, linux, sockets, timer, client-server

I am faced with a situation to maintain multiple timers in my socket communication program in C language. I have a client server program where both the client and the server ought to maintain a timer for every packet it send to the other machine. 
The protocol I am works like this-
Every packet that machine A sends, machine B must acknowledge the same in a certain time. So a timer has to be there for every packet that machine A sends. If the timer senses timeout the socket connection must close. 
This way I need to maintain timers for each and every packet. The time for time-out is same for all the packets. I am looking to know if there is any provision in C to set different timers and distinguish among them to achieve the functionality above.

Comment: Are you using UDP, or some other datagram-oriented protocol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of multiple timers, you can have one timer and a queue of "events". The queue is ordered by the time of the events. So when you send a packet, just add a disconnect-event to the event queue, and store some identifier to that event. If you receive a reply before the event fires, then remove the event from the queue.

Comment: Working on your suggestion improved by my colleague. Will post the status of the result once tested. Thanks

Comment: +1 for delta queue - the only way I know of handling timeouts across thousands of clients.

Comment: Also note that, since 'The time for time-out is same for all the packets', a simple FIFO queue will do - you don't need to sort the queue on insertion, just add at end.  If you have some sort of status variable in the 'events' that can be set to 'no action', you can also avoid removing elements from the middle of the queue, so avoiding copying down the elements above the one removed.  The state-variable/machine in the 'event' may have to be protected by a critical section, depending on your timer mechansim and overall design.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a precise answer to what you are looking for, one of the ways you could do is create on either side (both at the client and the server) a pool of packets waiting for their ACKs, with each packet in the pool marked for its *time-to-live*.

Packets are then kicked out of the pool as soon as their ACK(s) are received. For packets that remain in the wait - the pool is *watched* by some keeper which could be clocked by a global Timer, and all the keeper does is decrements the TTL periodically for each packet in the pool (say every N ticks). Packets for which the ACK(s) did not come in time (TTL reached 0) are declared timed-out and sockets handled.